# Telethon async and await mess

Tags: python, async-await, telegram, telethon

Here is my code as follows:

```py
import time
import telethon
import asyncio

# Enter your API ID and API hash here
api_id = 13******
api_hash = '8ba0a***********************'

# Enter the name of the text file containing the messages
message_file = 'messages.txt'

async def main():
    # Connect to the Telegram API using your API ID and API hash
    client = telethon.TelegramClient('sender', api_id, api_hash)

    # Read the messages from the text file
    with open(message_file, 'r') as f:
        messages = f.readlines()

    # Send the messages and pause for one minute between each message
    for message in messages:
        await client.send_message('@Example_recipient', message.strip())
        await time.sleep(60)

    # Disconnect from the Telegram API
    client.disconnect()

async def run() -> asyncio.coroutine:
    await main()

asyncio.run(run())
```

Whenever I run it, it gives me this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 173, in send
    raise ConnectionError('Cannot send requests while disconnected')
ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected
```

asyncio.run fixed a previous error which was:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'run' was never awaited
  run()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Now I am stuck with this new error that I can't seem to get around.

Comment: do you try to await `client `?

Comment: @codester_09 yes but it throws the following error:

line 14
    await client = telethon.TelegramClient('sender', api_id, api_hash)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to await expression here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?

Comment: There's no point in `await`ing `time.sleep`: it's a blocking op. You possibly want `asyncio.sleep`? Also from the first page of [their docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/) it looks like they provide a context manager, why are you manually calling disconnect instead of using it?

Comment: @JaredSmith asyncio.sleep(60), throws the same error. (raise ConnectionError('Cannot send requests while disconnected')
ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected)

i don't know where things go wrong that's why it's giving me nightmares

Comment: I don't know where you got your code from, but it's pretty far removed from the example in the documentation, which I've adapted to your code and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to something like this:

```
import asyncio
import telethon

api_id = 13******
api_hash = '8ba0a***********************'
message_file = 'messages.txt'

# Better style would be to have these not initiated
# at the top-level and instead behind the if name == main
# guard, but lets keep it simple.
client = telethon.TelegramClient('sender', api_id, api_hash)
with open(message_file, 'r') as f:
    messages = f.readlines()

async def main():
    for message in messages:
        await client.send_message('@Example_recipient', message.strip())
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # The context manager will release the resource
    # (i.e. call client.disconnect) for us when the
    # block exits.
    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

which is much closer to the [example in the documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html). Also it's not clear why you have the 60 second wait, or why you are using asyncio if you want to wait between sending messages. It looks like you could just use `telethon.sync` and block and not have any of the asyncio boilerplate?

### Update based on comments

```
with open(file) as handle:
    messages = list(handle.readlines())

...

    while len(messages):
        first = messages.pop()
        # check here before popping that the list
        # isn't already empty
        second = messages.pop()
        await client.send_message(first)
        await client.send_message(second)
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works as expected but i thought the original code was supposed to send 2 messages, remove them from the text file and then repeat until the file is empty..

Comment: @MohaMoney that would be much more complicated logic. First you're going to have to deal with errors: should the message be stripped from the file if the send fails? Overall though I would (assuming the size is reasonable) shove the messages into a list, pop off two at a time, append them to a failed list, and then overwrite the contents of the text file at the end of the program with the failed list.

Comment: well forget the stripping part, how would i go about sending 2 messages at a time without removing them from the file? for example line 1 of the file is "1" and line 2 is "2". i want it to send 1 and then 2 both in separate messages then wait 60 seconds then repeat.. can't get around it every time it sends the same "1" twice then waits and sends "2" twice and so on...

Comment: I posted an update to my answer. You'll need to add some error handling and a check around the length before popping off the second message, but should give the idea.

Comment: thank you very much for helping me with this, although i still don't know where to place the code that you posted later..

Comment: The `while` loop should replace the `for` loop, and add the list construction around the readlines operation. The `pop` method destructively modifies the list, which you can then use to overwrite the text file when you're all done sending messages.

Comment: i appreciate your help.. life saver thanks again